# Is there a shortcut to explicit named paramers when I call a method in C# for VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

In C# I have a method with many parameters.
I want to call that method with all named parameters.
Is there a shortcut to do this in VisualStudio 2017?
I use EF6 and have methods generated from stored procedures with more than 10 input params, with SQL 2014.

Method:

```
public void Test(int a, int b, int c){}
```

I'd like to autogenerate the following call to let easily adding values

```
Test(a: , b: , c: );
```

Is this possible? Or any ideas of a better approach?
Thank you!

Comment: as per this answer, Resharper will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659280/automated-refactoring-to-add-parameter-names-to-method-calls

Comment: Resharper can do this for you, for individual methods up to entire projects: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Argument_Style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension. Utilizing Roslyn you can find parameter names and types. Having types you can additionally insert default values for your common types.

For a sample code see [Insert explicit named parameters for a method call](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#NamedParameters). For your example it will insert `a: 0, b: 0, c: 0`.