# Autocompleting function with named argument template for coding convenience and accuracy

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working with Visual Studio and I'd like to begin calling a function and have the editor create a named function call template by pressing CTRL+Some_key.

Update: Just to be clear, I'm looking for functionality that works on every function call... so it would need to be able to analyze the preceding function, retrieve the argument names from the function definition, and put them into a templated form.

Example: Let's say I have a function as follows:

```
void MyFunction(int someInt, string someString, bool someBool){...}
```

I'd like to type "MyFunction(", press a shortcut and have the editor create something like the following for me:

```
MyFunction(
        someInt:
        , someString:
        , someBool:
)
```

It would also be amazing if I could edit the format of what it comes up with somewhere in Settings or actually be able to create multiple templates that I can select in a pop-up drop down.

If anyone is aware of this functionality, I'd appreciate any help. If it doesn't exist, I'm also interested in an effective way to request as a feature. And if you'd like to see this feature, please reply!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Visual Studio calls them "snippets": https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can a snippet analyze the function and retrieve the arguments for it? I'm looking for something that works for all functions, so it'd need to figure out what how many arguments and what they are called for the preceding function. Will update original post to make that clear.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849674/is-there-a-shortcut-to-explicit-named-paramers-when-i-call-a-method-in-c-sharp-f

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I'll post this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own code snippet.

1. Create an XML file with the code snippet.
2. In VS, go to

> Tools > Code Snippets Manager

and import your file. You can find a complete explanation here [Creating a Code Snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see how I can use a snippet for this specific function... but can I make one snippet that analyzes the function being called and creates a template with the correct named arguments? Meaning one snippet that applies to any preceding function. I can dig a little deeper, I'm thinking I'd need to be able to be able to retrieve the function arguments and loop through them inside the CDATA portion of the snippet. I couldn't find a snippet example that retrieved arguments from a function... doesn't mean it doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sergey Vlasov's comment, this has been asked at the following link:

[Is there a shortcut to explicit named paramers when I call a method in C# for VisualStudio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849674/is-there-a-shortcut-to-explicit-named-paramers-when-i-call-a-method-in-c-sharp-f)

The Visual Commander extension looks like it will do exactly this!

Resharper also looks viable, but it's not free.

Snippets might get you halfway to this kind of functionality, but not sure if they can retrieve the function arguments like Visual Commander does.